# Combine scopes from multiple instances of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Is there a way to 'combine' (if that's the right word?) scopes from multiple instances of a model object?  For example:

```
class Order
  scope :made_today, -> { where(date: Date.today) }
  has_many :products
end
```

If I try:

```
Order.made_today.products
```

I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'products' for #<Order::ActiveRecord_Relation:...>`

What's the most efficient way to achieve this? Hopefully, as a single SQL statement, letting the database do all the grunt.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with "combining scopes", you simply can't invoke an association on a *collection* of records. You couldn't use `Order.products` either.

If you want to get all products for a collection of records, you need to join against that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ActiveRecord Relations the opposite direction:

```
Product.where(order: Order.made_today)
```

Further, this should only require a single SQL query.

Note: As @maegar has explained, this isn't for a single order. For that you'd want to be handling an instance of an order:

```
@order = Order.made_today.first
@order.products #=> [<Product>, <Product>]
```